# wpf Resource template not applied

Tags: wpf, xaml, templates, resources, mvvm-light

I got a ResourceDictionary `CustomStyles.xaml` and i've implemented it in two views.
In the first view all templates and styles are working just fine. Though in the second view my Templates aren't applied to my `DataGrid` and when i enter the view the following output is shown. Still in my VS2012 Designer the `HeaderTemplates` are shown correct.

```
System.Windows.ResourceDictionary Warning: 9 : Resource not found; ResourceKey='TransparentWhiteBrush'
System.Windows.ResourceDictionary Warning: 9 : Resource not found; ResourceKey='TransparentWhiteBrush'
System.Windows.ResourceDictionary Warning: 9 : Resource not found; ResourceKey='GrayBrush7'
System.Windows.ResourceDictionary Warning: 9 : Resource not found; ResourceKey='Gray3'
System.Windows.ResourceDictionary Warning: 9 : Resource not found; ResourceKey='Gray3'
System.Windows.ResourceDictionary Warning: 9 : Resource not found; ResourceKey='ControlBackgroundBrush'
System.Windows.ResourceDictionary Warning: 9 : Resource not found; ResourceKey='TextBrush'
System.Windows.ResourceDictionary Warning: 9 : Resource not found; ResourceKey='GrayBrush7'
System.Windows.ResourceDictionary Warning: 9 : Resource not found; ResourceKey='TextBrush'
System.Windows.ResourceDictionary Warning: 9 : Resource not found; ResourceKey='TransparentWhiteBrush'
System.Windows.ResourceDictionary Warning: 9 : Resource not found; ResourceKey='TransparentWhiteBrush'
System.Windows.ResourceDictionary Warning: 9 : Resource not found; ResourceKey='GrayBrush7'
System.Windows.ResourceDictionary Warning: 9 : Resource not found; ResourceKey='Gray3'
System.Windows.ResourceDictionary Warning: 9 : Resource not found; ResourceKey='Gray3'
```

these Resources are not mine and i've not applied them in my view. 
My implemented Resources:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Fluent;Component/Themes/Office2010/Silver.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Fluent;Component/Themes/Office2010/Silver.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/Fluent;Component/Themes/Metro/White.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colours.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/PQS;component/Resources/CustomStyles.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

and finally my Datatemplate:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items.View}" Style="{DynamicResource InputDataGridStyle}" Grid.Row="1" Name="InputGrid" Loaded="InputGrid_Loaded" KeyUp="InputGrid_OnKeyUp">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn HeaderTemplate="{DynamicResource InputGridIndexHeaderTempalte}" CellTemplate="{DynamicResource InputGridIndexCellTempalte}" />

        <DataGridTemplateColumn HeaderTemplate="{DynamicResource InputGridTimeStampHeaderTemplate}" CellTemplate="{DynamicResource InputGridTimeStampCellTemplate}" />

        <DataGridTemplateColumn HeaderTemplate="{DynamicResource InputGridUserHeaderTemplate}" CellTemplate="{DynamicResource InputGridUserCellTemplate}" />

        <DataGridTemplateColumn HeaderTemplate="{DynamicResource InputGridValueHeaderTemplate}" CellTemplate="{DynamicResource InputGridValueCellTempalte}" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=InputGrid, Path=DataContext.CharacteristicMeasure.Characteristic.CharacteristicType.IsBool,Converter={StaticResource boolToInv}, ConverterParameter=true}" />

        <DataGridTemplateColumn HeaderTemplate="{DynamicResource InputGridValueHeaderTemplate}" CellTemplate="{DynamicResource InputGridBoolValueCellTempalte}" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=InputGrid, Path=DataContext.CharacteristicMeasure.Characteristic.CharacteristicType.IsBool,Converter={StaticResource boolToInv}}" />

        <DataGridTemplateColumn HeaderTemplate="{DynamicResource InputGridValidHeaderTemplate}" CellTemplate="{DynamicResource InputGridValidCellTemplate}" />

        <DataGridTemplateColumn HeaderTemplate="{DynamicResource InputGridTextHeaderTemplate}" CellTemplate="{DynamicResource InputGridTextCellTemplate}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

e.g. one header- and cell-template

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="InputGridIndexHeaderTempalte">
    <TextBlock Text="#" />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="InputGridIndexCellTempalte">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Index}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

screenshot of my designer
[image]

and here how it looks at the application:
[image]

please help!!! and ask if you need more information!

Comment: IN the first datagridTemplateColumn you misspelled the name of you data template. Where are you defining the resources dictionary in App.xaml?  What does your CustomStyles.xaml look like?

Comment: here is my CustomStyles.xaml : http://pastebin.com/U54KmFi3 ; and my view: http://pastebin.com/CjVUs5at ; i have not applied the resource to my App.xaml. i've applied it to my view.

Comment: THank you for your hint!!!! i added it to my App.xaml - know it works.. was kind of desperate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didnt had my xaml `ResourceDictionary` in my `App.xaml`. I dont know why... though if i place it there it all works fine.